# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named , can not find what causes the error in a Django application

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I face the following error when I run the

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

command

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/PIM/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/PIM/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/PIM/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/PIM/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/PIM/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/connect/Desktop/PIM/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rock_n_roll'
```

I can't seem to find where the error is coming from, any help ?

Comment: Have you got some code that does something like `from rock_n_roll import blah`? Because what that's suggesting is something is trying to access a file/module called `rock_n_roll` which doesn't exist where it's expecting it.

Comment: @markwalker_ not at all

Comment: The error is saying that you have "rock_n_roll" in your INSTALLED_APPS setting. Are you really saying that you don't?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I don't

Comment: Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. You could try temporarily commenting out entries to see which one is causing the error. Make sure you have saved your files and restarted you server after making changes so that you are definitely running the code you think you are.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks that helped